# Given a constant R,C, and the input voltage at any time, what is the output of a low pass rc circuit?

Tags: low-pass, transient

In other words, what is the transient response Vo(t) of any arbitrary input signal for a continuous voltage input Vi(t) for a low pass filter?

We can make some assumptions:

A for any given Vo(t), we only know Vi(n) from n=0 to t.

R and C are constant.

Vo(t) cannot be discretized, that is to say whatever method is used to calculate Vo, must not be iterative, and should not be a running / recursive method.

I've tried so far is the differential equation 
Dvo/Dt = (vi(t)-vo(t))(1-e^(-1/RC)), but this doesn't accurately reflect known responses.

Comment: What have you attempted so far? Show your working. This is not a free homework site.

Comment: @SolarMike well, I've tried using a discrete method involving the transient DC equation, and an initial voltage, but so far, it seems that with a small enough time difference, the results don't converge.

Comment: Usually it's t/τ not 1/τ .. Have you learned how to web search yet?

Comment: You need to develop an equation based on [\$i = C\dfrac{dv}{dt}\$](https://www.dummies.com/education/science/science-electronics/analyze-a-series-rc-circuit-using-a-differential-equation/).